# Adding items to listview at runTime shows blank list even when there are 23 items present

Tags: android, listview, adapter

i am calling this to add items at run time after every new load:

```
VideoListAdapter adapter=new VideoListAdapter(DashboardActivity.this, R.layout.dashboard_list_row, videoEntityList);
                videoList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am adding items to my videoEntityList.

I have also registered on touch and dropListner on list view can it be a issue?

Comment: Are yu adding item before submitting it videolist ?

Comment: Yes, I am adding items before submitting to list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was i was using a thread to notify my adapter after each 2 seconds to show changes from background. That was making my adapter blank.
Commenting that block solved my problem.
Thanks any way.....

Answer (score 0):

try to log the size of videoEntityList may be it's length was 0 or you donont add item properly before intializing try this Log.d("Size of array is","=="+videoEntityList.size());

Comment: ok if you have an elements in that so check the visibility of your listview in your xml file